# Miniaturize pdf with css and html

Tags: html, css

I am looking to miniaturize a pdf in css and html.
when I click on my button it shows the pdf in a new tab, but I would like to see this pdf in small before clicking.

Is it possible ?

Comment: Yes it's possible, you probably want to show it in a lightbox. However, your question isn't really worth putting on here, as there's no programming element to it. Take a look at fancybox - http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main use of providing a miniaturized preview is to save bandwidth. So you probably wanto to provide some smaller version (e.g. a static image of the first page in .png format) of the PDF you want to preview, and will probably need some server-side scripting framework with PDF support, e.g. python-django, ruby-sinatra, php or the like.